# Awake phone from sleep with chronometer timer

Tags: android

I am making an interval timer for a stopwatch APP, and I'm using chronometer to display notifications (Run, walk, stop) and play sound. But when the phone is in sleepmode it doesn't do anything.

Is there a way to wake up the phone, to show these notifications (and play the sound), or must I use AlarmManager?

I know how to make the phone stay awake with wakelock and FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, but I don't know how to awake it from sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager`. There is nothing else timer-based that will wake up the device out of sleep mode.

Comment: Is it possible to combine AlarmManager and Chronometer?

Comment: @janlindso: To the same extent that you can "combine" `AlarmManager` and an `Integer`, or `AlarmManager` and a `Restaurant`. When your `AlarmManager` `PendingIntent` is executed, what you do at that point is up to you, and can certainly include ensuring that your `Chronometer` is showing whatever you deem the proper value to be.